# can't create .db file Django

Tags: django, sqlite

I'm using sqlite3 and and after I python manage.py syncdb it's supposed to create a database file (called sqlite3.db) It doesn't do this. I've tried searching for the file and I've tried running all the commands as Administrator and normal user. No luck so far.

What's going wrong here? I would reallly appreciate some help here!

Here's the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 14, in <module> execute_manager(settings)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle return self.handle_noargs(**options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 56, in handle_noargs cursor = connection.cursor() 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 250, in cursor cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 201, in _cursor raise ImproperlyConfigured("Please fill out the database NAME in the settings module before using the database.") 
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Please fill out the database NAME in the settings module before using the database.
```

Btw I'm not using the latest Django. I'm using Django 1.3
My OS is Linux Mint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear. You haven't specified the NAME in settings.py. Django can't create the db for until you tell it what name to use.